# Show / hide password on button click Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-button

How to switch between hide and view password in *Xamarin* Android on `button` click?

```
private void _viewPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    EditText _editTextNew = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTxtPwd_signup);
    if (_editTextNew.InputType== Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword) {
        _editTextNew.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;
        _editTextNew.SetSelection(_editTextNew.Text.Length);
    }
    else if(_editTextNew.InputType == Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText) {
        _editTextNew.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword;
        _editTextNew.SetSelection(_editTextNew.Text.Length);
    }                             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might should use [`TextVariationVisiblePassword`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword/), and `TextVariationPassword` with `ClassText` as you already did. But to be sure to get your condition, I suggest to use a global `Boolean`:

```
private void _viewPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (_isPasswordHidden) {
        _editText.InputType = 
            Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword 
            | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;

    } else {
        _editText.InputType = 
             Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword 
             | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;
    }

    _isPasswordHidden = !_isPasswordHidden;
}
```